# not properly inserts the new node at the end of a linked llist

Tags: c, list, unix

I am trying to create a linked list from data read from a file.
The following code is included in a while loop.
Seems like the data are picked correctly but not inserted properly in the list, since when i try to print the data of the list using the head, i notice that the head seems to be moved on the next node every time. 
Any help here?

```
    newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    newNode ->name=name;
    newNode->number=no;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = newNode;
        head->next=NULL;
        temp=head;
    }

    else{
        newNode->next = temp->next;
        temp->next=newNode;
        temp=newNode; 
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through your code? If not, that's the first (and by far the most educational) thing you should try.

Comment: yes i tried to debug, and i see that indeed enters in the if statement the first time, while head is null. The rest times enters in else block, but when i try to print the data of the node where the head points, doesnt give the data of the first node evry time, but the data of the current node. looks like all pointers are moving to the current node, including the head

Comment: In the else statement kill the first line. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since the head is the first node of the list, the problem I see is that you create the newNode properly at the beginning, and the if branch seems to work fine. However, the else branch is the one that seems to be causing the problem, it should look something like this:

```
if(head == NULL){
    head = newNode;
    head->next = NULL;
    temp = head;
} else {
    temp->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL; //Since, as you said, the list is just reading from a file, the last element inserted will be the last of the list until a new one is read.
    temp = newNode; 
}
```

Good luck, hope this helps!

EDIT:
Try to just enter a pointer to the newNode instead of just newNode, the problem you describe above seems to be that every element points to the last one, this could solve it:

```
if(head == NULL){
    head = newNode;
    head->next = NULL;
    temp = head;
} else {
    temp->next = *newNode;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    temp = newNode; 
}
```

PS: In your version, it would be

```
temp->next=*newNode;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but i am afraid this doesn't solve the issue :( it is pretty much the same as i already have it there :(

Comment: There is a difference between my version and yours, essentially the first line of yours, I understand how yours should work too, but I believe the version I posted should be easier to debug and it's clearer to understand in my opinion. Good luck with that anyway and please let me know when you find what's wrong!

Comment: Please try this new solution and let me know! :)